# JavaFX 8: Handling maximize request before it's actually done

Tags: java, javafx-8, maximize-window

I need to change effect of clicking maximize button of the stage, so it will be just put into another stage. But to achieve that, I need to handle maximize request before it's actually done. I tried this:

```
stage.maximizedProperty().addListener( (observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
{
    //. . .
});
```

But it's invoked too late and the stage has been already maximized. Even if I hide it, there is an ugly view when window maximizes and then it quickly disappears. So is there any way to make it work properly?